# ggplot2 in R: Calculate percentage and make a graph that might be a geom_area plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm a beginner in R, so please be patient with me if there are very obvious mistakes in my code and for my question! For a homework problem, I am struggling to make what I think is a geom_area plot look like this:

[image: geom_area plot]

As background, we are using the diamonds dataframe from ggplot2 library. We were given the plot and asked to reproduce it. My biggest problem is with the y-axis. The graph given indicated that the y-axis represents density, which I think is the percentage/proportion of each clarity grade given the title. Originally, I thought perhaps I needed to create a new dataframe with "Price" and "Clarity Proportion (or, density)", but I wasn't sure how to do that. The professor hinted that we should not need to create a new variable for this problem.

Here's what I have so far. It produces the error message: "In Ops.ordered(left, right): '/' is not meaningful for ordered factors":

```
set.seed(123)
d <- ggplot(diamonds[sample(nrow(diamonds),5000),]) #these were given in the homework
d + geom_area(aes(x = price, y = lapply(count(diamonds$clarity), FUN = count(diamonds$clarity)/53940), colour = clarity), position = "fill") +
   labs(title = "Clarity Proportion by Price")
```

I know my y-axis is wrong, but I'm just not sure how to transform it. Your explanation and insight are greatly appreciated!

Comment: For starters, you have an extra comma at the end of your geom_area call

Comment: If you are not supposed to precompute statistics, then you should look into the `stat_` functions in `ggplot2`. These are what allow you to transform data before plotting

Comment: You don't need `geom_area`. It's a stacked density plot. `d + geom_density(aes(x = price, fill = clarity), position = "fill")` would work.